# can't install jre ( java runtime enviornment ) in ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: installation, 10.10, jre

I know my Ubuntu 10.10 is no more supported. I want to install JaxoDraw and for that I need to install JRE ( Java Runtime Enviornment ). Is there any way to install it manually?
Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unsupported End-of-Life version of Ubuntu. Please upgrade to a supported release so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a JRE directy from the [Oracle Technet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

The download is available for Linux 32-bit and 64-bit Systems as a `tar.gz` file which simply is unpacked into the destination.